# Twitter Search Api Getting Username and User's Real Name

Tags: json, twitter, jsonp, twitter-search

I am trying to develop a twitter search engine by reference of https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search. I am faced to a problem; I searched about it I could not find anything.

```
$.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" +search_value + "&rpp=5&callback=?",
            success: function(data){
                // Display the results

                $("#search_results").html(data);
            }
    });
```

As you know, twitter api returns a json according your search like in this link "https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search       (In the Example Request part)

I need the "username" and the "real name of user" about tweet results, in json format I couldn't see and also I looked https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities but there is no tip about this. Only there is "The user_mentions entity", but this users are mentioned in tweet text not about sharer of tweet. Could you help me about this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you update your code to use the latest version of the Twitter REST API - version 1.1 as opposed to using the Search API.

The v1.1 API returns the user's real name in the `search/tweets` JSON response - see example response here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

Comment: What do you mean by "update your code to use the latest version of the Twitter API - version 1.1.", could you explain? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You're currently using the Search API, so if you want to get the user name back in the JSON response you'll need to have you code talk to the REST API v1.1. That means using this endpoint: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json as opposed to the URL you are currently using. The link I gave in my answer explains how to supply query parameters to that endpoint.